# WPF: How to animate color change?

Tags: wpf, animation, coloranimation

I have a grid, a window root element. I want to apply an animation which would change it's background color from white to green in 5 seconds. Here's what I did:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation animation;

    animation = new ColorAnimation();
    animation.From = Colors.White;
    animation.To = Colors.Green;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    rootElement.BeginAnimation(Grid.BackgroundProperty, animation);
}
```

The code doesn't work. Nothing is changing. Where am I making a mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved!

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush rootElementBrush;
    ColorAnimation animation;

    rootElementBrush = this.FindResource("RootElementBrush") as SolidColorBrush;

    // Animate the brush 
    animation = new ColorAnimation();
    animation.To = Colors.Green;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    rootElementBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
}
```

Here's an explanation:

My initial mistake was that I wanted to change the `Grid.BackgroundProperty` by assigning colors to it, but it accepts brushes instead... apples and oranges! So, I created a `SolidColorBrush` static resource and named it rootElementBrush. In XAML, I set `Grid rootElement`'s background property to that static resource. And finally, I modified the animation, so now it changes the color for that `SolidColorBrush`. Easy!

Comment: Glad you were able to get this resolved. You should select your own answer as the one which you have accepted here.

Comment: @zedo I know, but it tells me I won't be able to mark it correct in the next two days. It's waiting for things to cool down first, hahahaha

Comment: how to set "from" white "to" orignal image color?

Answer (score 15):

Give this a try:

```
<ColorAnimation
Storyboard.TargetName="PlayButtonArrow" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
From="White"
To="Green"              
Duration="0:0:5.0"
AutoReverse="False"/>
```

Comment: I need it in code-behind and also I need to call it from code-behind. I am thinking that I might be making a mistake in my code because I am trying to change a color, but `Grid.Background` property is actually taking a brush...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the `StaticResource`, just use the `Storyboard`.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Animate the brush 
    ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
    animation.To = Colors.Green;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)", null));
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.Begin(rootElement);
}
```